# How To Get Article's Users and Comments With Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There are three database tables users, articles and a joining table article_users_comments, which holds the comment, the user id commented the article and the commented article id.

I can achieve the following thing with pure SQL join, but I want to do it with Eloquent, I thought that it would be quite easy, but I am kind of confused right now.

I have been trying different things, but it still doesn't work.

```
// User

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail,CanResetPassword{

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ArticleComments');
    }

}

// Article

class Article extends Model{


    public function getArticles(){
        $articles = Article::paginate(3);
        return $articles;
    }

    public function getSingleArticle($title){

        $article = Article::where('title','=',$title)->get();
        return $article;
    }

    public function articleComments()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\ArticleComments');
    }

}

// ArticleComments

class ArticleComments extends Model{
      protected $table = 'article_users_comments';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}

// ArticleController(showing only the show method), which passes the data to the certain view 
instantiating the Article Model 

class ArticleController extends Controller{

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($title)
    {
        $removeDashesFromUrl = str_replace('-',' ',$title);
         $am = new Article();
         $data = $am->getSingleArticle($removeDashesFromUrl);
         return view('article',['article'=>$data]);
    }


}
```

I want to get the comments and the users(which have commented the article) for a certain certain article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the foreign key in your `articleComments` and `article` relations:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id. However, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method:

**Article Model**

```
 public function articleComments()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\ArticleComments','commented_article_id');
 }
```

**ArticleComments Model**

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Article','commented_article_id');
}
```

You can get the comments from a article using the relation:

```
$article = Article::find($id);
$article->articleComments; // This will return all comments for the given article
```

You could use a foreach loop and access each attribute from each comment:

```
foreach($article->articleComments as $comment)
{
  echo $comment->id;
  echo $comment->user->id;
  echo $comment->user->username;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

You can access the user and any of his attributes just calling the relation in your comment like i did above.

For more info: [click here.](http://Eloquent%20determines%20the%20default%20foreign%20key%20name%20by%20examining%20the%20name%20of%20the%20relationship%20method%20and%20suffixing%20the%20method%20name%20with%20_id.%20However,%20if%20the%20foreign%20key%20on%20the%20Phone%20model%20is%20not%20user_id,%20you%20may%20pass%20a%20custom%20key%20name%20as%20the%20second%20argument%20to%20the%20belongsTo%20method:)

**Note:** i strongly recommend you changing your model name to **Comment**, we don't use model names in the plural, always in singular.